# OSX 10.11 (El Capitan beta) pf.conf behaviour changed?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, pf

I kind of expected things to break, but ...

My pf forwarding rules, which worked previously on Yosemite, no longer work on 10.11.

My forwarding rule is as follows: `rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080`

I can access the content by going to `localhost:8080`, but not just `localhost,` which is expect (and previous) behaviour.

Did they mention somewhere changes to the pf utility? What do I have to do to make this work?

Comment: Are you piping the pf rule to `pfctl`? If so, can you update your question to include this example.

Comment: I encountered the same problem after upgrading to 10.11. I followed [this advice](https://echo.co/blog/os-x-1010-yosemite-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew) to forward port 80 requests to 8080 with the following: `echo "rdr pass proto tcp from any to any port {80,8080} -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080" | pfctl -a "com.apple/260.HttpFwdFirewall" -Ef`

Comment: I have the same problem... But I can't get it to work. Did you just paste this command in the terminal? I get this error: `pfctl: option requires an argument -- f` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517368/using-pfctl-on-mac-os-10-11-el-capitan-to-forward-ports?noredirect=1#comment51030050_31517368

Comment: @Dafen the -f command requires a file. I think, if you drop that argument, the error will go away.

Comment: ^ following the above, @williamcwilliams command does not work for me.

Comment: I upgraded to the Beta Preview 4 and it works again. Same file as on Yosemite. I posted my config here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517368/using-pfctl-on-mac-os-10-11-el-capitan-to-forward-ports/31570667#31570667

Answer (score 1):

**This only applies to OSX 10.11 - El Capitan - Public Beta 1**

In the latest 10.11 beta, 127.0.0.1 is blocked.  The solution?  Use 127.0.0.2.  To do this:

First add 127.0.0.2 to the loopback alias
`sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2 up`

Modify your pf rule to use the the new alias.
`rdr pass proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.2 port 8080`

For @williamcwilliams (in comments above), just drop the anchor and it'll work.

`echo "rdr pass proto tcp from any to any port {80,8080} -> 127.0.0.2 port 8080" | pfctl -Ef -`  <-- Be sure to add this last tick, you're piping in STDIN)

Comment: Why is 127.0.0.1 blocked?

Comment: Likely a bug in the beta.

Comment: It works again with 10.11 Beta 4 =)